# Making my span class row, reset and submit button horizontal instead of one on top of the other

Tags: html, css

Hello all I am very new to HTML and CSS and am currently working on a small lab for school. I am trying to have my two reset and submit button be horizontal with each other instead, they are one on top of the other. I am not supposed to change any of the HTML just make changes to the CSS code. The buttons are in a span element at the bottom. I added my form code to add more context

```
<form>
    <span class="row">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Jaylen Carroll">
    </span>
    <span class="row">
        <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
        <input type="date" id="dob" name="dob">
    </span>
    <span class="row">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="jaylen@gmail.com">
    </span>
    <span class="row">
        <label for="city">City</label>
        <input type="city" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Ottawa">
    </span>
    <span class="row">
        <label for="province">Province</label>
        <select id="province" name="province">
            <option>Please Select..</option>
            <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
            <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
            <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
            <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
            <option value="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
            <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
            <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
            <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
            <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
            <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
            <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
            <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
            <option value="YT">Yukon</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span class="row">
        <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
    </span>
</form>
```

When you paste the code in an HTML editor it comes out like this:
[image: How the HTML comes out]

How I need it to be:
[image]

My Css code looks like this:

```
h1{
text-align:center;
}
label{
margin-top: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
display: block;
text-align: center;
font-size: medium;
}
input{
text-align:center;
display: block;
margin: 15px;
width:150px;
}
form{
margin:0 auto;
width:215px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML elements start on separate lines by default. One solution would be to put your buttons in a group with a div element then use the float CSS property to horizontally align them.

HTML

```
<div class="button-group">
  <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset">
   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button-group input {
    float: left;
    }
```

You can refer to this w3 schools link for more information on button groups:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_group.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can use [display flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
This defines a flex container; inline or block depending on the given value. It enables a flex context for all its direct children.

Set [flex:direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) as column.

This establishes the main-axis, thus defining the direction flex items are placed in the flex container. Flexbox is (aside from optional wrapping) a single-direction layout concept. Think of flex items as primarily laying out either in horizontal rows or vertical columns.

```css
.row{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <span class="row">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Jaylen Carroll">
    </span>
    <span class="row">
        <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
        <input type="date" id="dob" name="dob">
    </span>
    <span class="row">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="jaylen@gmail.com">
    </span>
    <span class="row">
        <label for="city">City</label>
        <input type="city" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Ottawa">
    </span>
    <span class="row">
        <label for="province">Province</label>
        <select id="province" name="province">
            <option>Please Select..</option>
            <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
            <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
            <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
            <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
            <option value="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
            <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
            <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
            <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
            <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
            <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
            <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
            <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
            <option value="YT">Yukon</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span class="row">
        <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
    </span>
</form>
```

Comment: This does work for me but, I only want it affecting the two buttons to be horizontal, when I address the ".row" in the style sheet, it affects all the rows in the HTML when I only need to change the Submit and Reset button.

Answer (score 0):

for the last class row which contains the 2 buttons you can replace its class name and apply this CSS to it

```css
.class-name {
  display:"flex",
  // if you want to keep space between the two buttons
  justify-content:"space-between"
  // if not don't put `justify-content` and instead put a margin to one of the buttons to
  // keep a little distance between them
}
```

so display "flex" is your friend when you want to group elements as a row